# How do I get the PHP debugger to break on breakpoints inside a docker container in VsCode?

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

- I have Xdebug installed and configured.
- I have the PHP-Debug extension installed in VsCode.
- I have the Remote-Containers extension installed in VsCode.
- I can attach to my running container in VsCode, and see the files inside the container.
- If I make a change in a file (e.g. change some text on the page), when I refresh the page in the browser the change is rendered.   So I know my file is being edited and saved inside the container.
- I can set a breakpoint in the file, but when I refresh the page, the breakpoint is not activated.   Why?   And how do I make breakpoints work?
- What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem using a different tech stack, but make sure all of your paths are correct in the launch.json and tasks.json file (i.e., pathMappings, dockerBuild nodes, etc)